# Converting number to words in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to write number to word function in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673265/how-to-write-number-to-word-function-in-sql-server)

Is it possible to convert a `number into words in SQL` Server.

EG: `12.5 as  Twelve point five`

Answer (score 2):

I found an interesting trick to do this in oracle

```
SELECT    TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (TRUNC (&num), 'J'), 'JSP')
       || ' Point '
       || TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (&num, INSTR (&num, '.') + 1)),'J'),'JSP')
  FROM DUAL;
```

I dnt have sql server installed, you can try it in sql server by replacing respective functions.

source:
http://www.club-oracle.com/forums/sql-to-convert-number-to-words-t657/