# Convert a number in Words with CAMA (number,number)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help in this please as I want to read numbers like the example below.

original value: `3 458,98`

return value:

`TROIS MILLE QUATRE CENT CINQUANTE HUIT EURO QUATRE VINGT DIX HUIT CENTIMES`

Comment: this may work in oracle (found online): `SELECT    TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (TRUNC (&num), 'J'), 'JSP')
       || ' Point '
       || TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (&num, INSTR (&num, '.') + 1)),'J'),'JSP')
  FROM DUAL;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486108/converting-any-number-in-words

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353008/converting-number-to-words-in-sql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673265/how-to-write-number-to-word-function-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
DECLARE @numbers VARCHAR(50) = '3458.98'
        , @WordsString varchar(max)

SELECT @WordsString = COALESCE(@WordsString + ', ', '')  + o.word
FROM 
(
SELECT 
CASE WHEN q.ch NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' AND q.ch = 3 THEN ' THREE'    
     WHEN q.ch NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' AND q.ch = 4 THEN ' FOUR'    
     WHEN q.ch NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' AND q.ch = 5 THEN ' FIVE'    
     WHEN q.ch NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' AND q.ch = 8 THEN ' EIGHT'    
     WHEN q.ch NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' AND q.ch = 9 THEN ' NINE'    
     ELSE Q.ch
   END word
FROM 
(select substring(a.b, v.number+1, 1) ch
from (select @numbers b) a
join master..spt_values v on v.number < len(a.b)
where v.type = 'P'
)q
)o

SELECT @WordsString
```

Output:

```
 THREE,  FOUR,  FIVE,  EIGHT, .,  NINE,  EIGHT
```

Comment: something like that but what i really need is this :
OUTPUT :
three thousand four hundred fifty eight $ ninety eight CENTS