# Generate text equivalent of numbers

Tags: mysql, sql-server, automation, generator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to write number to word function in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673265/how-to-write-number-to-word-function-in-sql-server)

Simple requirement, but cann't seem to find/search properly.

Do you know of a way that would generate for me:

```
1-->One
2-->Two
3-->Three
100-->One hundred
295-->Two hundred and ninety five
```

etc.

when I give a range of numbers.

Comment: Do you want to know how to translate a numeric value to   text (`100=One hundred`)? If so, i don't understand _"range of numbers"_.

Comment: @TimSchmelter  I do not want 'per number' service, where I type a number and I get its word equivalent, I should be able to give 'from' and 'to' numbers and should get word equivalents of everything in between.

Comment: mysql or sql-server - which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this serves my purpose:
[how to write number to word function in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673265/how-to-write-number-to-word-function-in-sql-server)

I am just looking for a way to quickly be able to generate word equivalents fo ra range of number. 'How' doesn't really matter.

The reason I posted the question is because I didn't use the correct search words before.

If I use 'word equivalent of numbers' for search on the web, I get the results I wanted, but I was searching using 'text equivalent..' instead.