# How we can get Output by MS Sql query with custom message and count?

Tags: sql-server

I want to make MS Sql query for the below data which give output as i want.

table Name: Emp(two columns EmpID int, VacantEndDate datetime)
table data:

```
EmpID  |  VacantEndDate
11     |  22-Jun-16
12     |  22-Jun-16
13     |  30-May-15
14     |  30-May-15
15     |  31-Mar-15
16     |  02-Dec-16
```

output by MS Sql query order by date

```
One Post Vacant on 31-Mar-16
Two Post vacant on 30-May-16
Two Post vacant on 22-Jun-16
One Post Vacant on 02-Dec-16
```

i try to make query but not get success, please help me

thanks in advance.

Comment: use `group by VacantEndDate` and `count()` function. You can then use `select case when (count(*) = 1) then 'One Post Vacant on'+cast([VacantEndDate] as nvarchar)` and so on.

Comment: Also see this for a more generic number to word function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673265/how-to-write-number-to-word-function-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script is casting the datetime to date to prevent timeparts in any of the datetimes. Different timeparts would cause extra rows when grouping.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE COUNT(*)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'One'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Two'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Three'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Four'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Five'
    WHEN 6 THEN 'Six'
    WHEN 7 THEN 'Seven'
    WHEN 8 THEN 'Eight'
    WHEN 9 THEN 'Nine'
    ELSE 'Ten+' 
    END + 
    ' Post Vacant on ' +
    REPLACE(CONVERT(char(9), CAST(VacantEndDate as date), 6), ' ', '-') 
FROM Emp
GROUP BY CAST(VacantEndDate as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query:-

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (COUNT(EmpID) = 1) THEN 'One Post Vacant on' + cast([VacantEndDate] AS NVARCHAR),
            WHEN (COUNT(EmpID) = 2) THEN 'Two Post Vacant on' + cast([VacantEndDate] AS NVARCHAR),
            WHEN (COUNT(EmpID) = 3) THEN 'Three Post Vacant on' + cast([VacantEndDate] AS NVARCHAR),
            WHEN (COUNT(EmpID) = 4) THEN 'Four Post Vacant on' + cast([VacantEndDate] AS NVARCHAR),
            WHEN (COUNT(EmpID) = 5) THEN 'Five Post Vacant on' + cast([VacantEndDate] AS NVARCHAR),
            WHEN (COUNT(EmpID) = 6) THEN 'Six Post Vacant on' + cast([VacantEndDate] AS NVARCHAR),
            WHEN (COUNT(EmpID) = 7) THEN 'Seven Post Vacant on' + cast([VacantEndDate] AS NVARCHAR),
            WHEN (COUNT(EmpID) = 8) THEN 'Eight Post Vacant on' + cast([VacantEndDate] AS NVARCHAR),
            WHEN (COUNT(EmpID) = 9) THEN 'Nine Post Vacant on' + cast([VacantEndDate] AS NVARCHAR)
FROM Emp
GROUP BY VacantEndDate
```

This might be helpful to you.