# Is there a built-in function that can convert numbers into words in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, data-conversion

I have a table `currency`:

```
Dollar  
------  
10   
100  
1000    
120.20
```

O/P

```
Dollar  
--------    
Ten dollar  
Hundred dollar  
One Thousand dollar  
One Hundred Twenty dollar and Twenty cents
```

Comment: So is there any how we can achieve??

Comment: Check this link https://forums.asp.net/t/1995435.aspx?How+to+convert+Number+to+word+using+Sql+Query+with+standard+US+as+UK+Fromat

Comment: Here is similar question asked in SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673265/how-to-write-number-to-word-function-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function, **Util_ToWords**, in the Free version of the [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com) SQLCLR library that I wrote that does this (well, without the "dollar(s)" and "cents" words added):

```sql
SELECT SQL#.Util_ToWords(10); -- Ten
SELECT SQL#.Util_ToWords(100); -- One Hundred
SELECT SQL#.Util_ToWords(1000); -- One Thousand 
SELECT SQL#.Util_ToWords(120.20); -- One Hundred Twenty and 20
SELECT SQL#.Util_ToWords(212); -- Two Hundred Twelve
SELECT SQL#.Util_ToWords(123097.4);-- One Hundred Twenty Three Thousand, Ninety Seven and 40
```

The following example injects the "dollar(s)" and "cents" words into the return value (which was originally intended for printing on checks):

```sql
DECLARE @Amount MONEY = 2.08;

;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT N' dollar' + CASE WHEN @Amount >= 1.00 AND @Amount < 2.00 THEN N''
              ELSE N's'
         END AS [Currency],
         SQL#.Util_ToWords(@Amount) AS [Words]
)
SELECT CASE CHARINDEX(N' and ', cte.[Words])
           WHEN 0 THEN cte.[Words] + cte.[Currency]
           ELSE STUFF(cte.[Words], CHARINDEX(N' and ', cte.[Words]), 0, cte.[Currency])
                + N' cents'
       END
FROM cte;
```

Returns:

```
Two dollars and 08 cents
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no built-in syntax for it. You will have to do it on your application or create a function. Then the converted amount will be stored to SQL Database.

Answer (score 0):

First Create a Function

```
Create    FUNCTION [dbo].[OneToNinetynine] (

@num int)   RETURNS VARCHAR(50) 

AS BEGIN
DECLARE @word VARCHAR(50)

set @word=''

 if @num =1 set @word='One'

 else if @num =2 set @word='Two'

 else if @num = 3    set @word='Three'

 else if @num = 4    set @word='Four'

else if @num =  5    set @word='Five'

else if @num =  6    set @word='Six'

else if @num =  7    set @word='Seven'

else if @num =  8    set @word='Eight'

else if @num =  9    set @word='Nine'

else if @num =  10   set @word='Ten'

else if @num =  11   set @word='Eleven'

else if @num =  12   set @word='Twelve'

else if @num =  13   set @word='Thirteen'

 else if @num = 14   set @word='Forteen'

 else if @num = 15   set @word='Fifteen'

 else if @num = 16   set @word='Sixteen'

else if @num =  17   set @word='Seventeen'

else if @num =  18   set @word='Eighteen'

else if @num =  19   set @word='Nineteen'

else if @num =  20   set @word='Twenty'

else if @num =  21   set @word='Twenty One '

else if @num =  22   set @word='Twenty Two'

else if @num =  23   set @word='Twenty Three'

else if @num =  24   set @word='Twenty Four'

else if @num =  25   set @word='Twenty Five'

else if @num =  26   set @word='Twenty Six'

else if @num =  27   set @word='Twenty Seven'

else if @num =  28   set @word='Twenty Eight'

else if @num =  29   set @word='Twenty Nine'

else if @num =  30   set @word='Thirty'

else if @num =  31   set @word='Thirty One '

else if @num =  32   set @word='Thirty Two'

else if @num =  33   set @word='Thirty Three'

else if @num =  34   set @word='Thirty Four'

else if @num =  35   set @word='Thirty Five'

else if @num =  36   set @word='Thirty Six'

else if @num =  37   set @word='Thirty Seven'

else if @num =  38   set @word='Thirty Eight'

else if @num =  39   set @word='Thirty Nine'

else if @num =  40   set @word='Forty'

else if @num =  41   set @word='Forty One'

else if @num =  42   set @word='Forty Two'

else if @num =  43   set @word='Forty Three'

else if @num =  44   set @word='Forty Four'

else if @num =  45   set @word='Forty Five'

else if @num =  46   set @word='Forty Six'

else if @num =  47   set @word='Forty Seven'

else if @num =  48   set @word='Forty Eight'

else if @num =  49   set @word='Forty Nine'

else if @num =  50   set @word='Fifty'

else if @num =  51   set @word='Fifty One'

else if @num =  52   set @word='Fifty Two'

else if @num =  53   set @word='Fifty Three'

else if @num =  54   set @word='Fifty Four'

else if @num =  55   set @word='Fifty Five'

else if @num =  56   set @word='Fifty Six'

 else if @num = 57   set @word='Fifty Seven'

else if @num =  58   set @word='Fifty Eight'

 else if @num = 59   set @word='Fifty Nine'

else if @num =  60   set @word='Sixty'

 else if @num = 61   set @word='Sixty One'

 else if @num = 62   set @word='Sixty Two'

else if @num =  63   set @word='Sixty Three'

else if @num =  64   set @word='Sixty Four'

 else if @num = 65   set @word='Sixty Five'

 else if @num = 66   set @word='Sixty Six'

 else if @num = 67   set @word='Sixty Seven'

 else if @num = 68   set @word='Sixty Eight'

 else if @num = 69   set @word='Sixty Nine'

else if @num =  70   set @word='Seventy'

 else if @num = 71   set @word='Seventy One '

 else if @num = 72   set @word='Seventy Two'

 else if @num = 73   set @word='Seventy Three'

 else if @num = 74   set @word='Seventy Four'

 else if @num = 75   set @word='Seventy Five'

 else if @num = 76   set @word='Seventy Six'
```

Then Use This Function

```
     Create    FUNCTION [dbo].[NumberToWord] (  

     @num numeric(16,2)  

 )   RETURNS VARCHAR(200)  

 AS BEGIN  


 DECLARE @word VARCHAR(200)  

 DECLARE @Dollar VARCHAR(200)  

 DECLARE @Cent VARCHAR(200)

 DECLARE @main int  

 DECLARE @Frac numeric(12,2)

 DECLARE @i int  

 set @word ='' 

 set @Dollar =''

 set @Cent=''

 IF(@num<1000000000)

 BEGIN


 set @main = convert(int,@num)  

 set @Frac = (@num - @main  )*100





 IF (@main>9999999)  

 Begin  

  set @Dollar=@Dollar+dbo.OneToNinetynine(@main/10000000)+'Crore ' 

  set @main= @main % 10000000  

 End  

 IF (@main>99999)

 Begin  

  set @Dollar=@Dollar+dbo.OneToNinetynine(@main/100000)+'Lac '  

  set @main= @main % 100000  

 End  

 IF (@main>999)  

 Begin

  set @Dollar=@Dollar+dbo.OneToNinetynine(@main/1000)+'Thousand '  

  set @main= @main % 1000  

 End  

 IF (@main>99)   

 Begin  

  set @Dollar=@Dollar+dbo.OneToNinetynine(@main/100)+'Hundred '  

  set @main= @main % 100 

 End  


 IF (@main>0)  

 Begin  

  set @Dollar=@Dollar+dbo.OneToNinetynine(@main)

 End  


 IF (@Frac>0)  

 Begin 

  set @Cent=dbo.OneToNinetynine(@Frac)  

 End  


 set @word = @Dollar

 if @Dollar <> '' set @word = @word + 'Dollar'

 if (@Dollar <> '' and @Cent <> '') set @word =@word +  ' And '

 if @Cent <> '' set @word =@word  +  @Cent + 'Paisa'

 set @word ='Tk-'+ @word + ' Only' 

 END   


 RETURN (@word)  
 END
```

Then Call the 2nd Function
select dbo.NumberToWord(24450999.89)

Answer (score 0):

--my version w/o CTE
--relies on 3 tables,

```html
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('dbo.Num38'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE dbo.Num38 (I int NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_Num38 PRIMARY KEY (I))
DECLARE @i int = 1
WHILE @i <= 38 BEGIN
 INSERT dbo.Num38 VALUES(@i)
 SELECT @i = @i+1
END
END 
GO
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('dbo.NumbersTable'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE dbo.NumbersTable (number CHAR(2) NOT NULL, word VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT PK_NumbersTable PRIMARY KEY (number))

INSERT INTO dbo.NumbersTable   
SELECT '00', 'Zero'
    UNION ALL SELECT '01', 'One'    UNION ALL SELECT '02', 'Two'
    UNION ALL SELECT '03', 'Three'    UNION ALL SELECT '04', 'Four'
    UNION ALL SELECT '05', 'Five'   UNION ALL SELECT '06', 'Six'
    UNION ALL SELECT '07', 'Seven'    UNION ALL SELECT '08', 'Eight'
    UNION ALL SELECT '09', 'Nine'   UNION ALL SELECT '10', 'Ten'
    UNION ALL SELECT '11', 'Eleven'   UNION ALL SELECT '12', 'Twelve'
    UNION ALL SELECT '13', 'Thirteen' UNION ALL SELECT '14', 'Fourteen'
    UNION ALL SELECT '15', 'Fifteen'  UNION ALL SELECT '16', 'Sixteen'
    UNION ALL SELECT '17', 'Seventeen' UNION ALL SELECT '18', 'Eighteen'
    UNION ALL SELECT '19', 'Nineteen' UNION ALL SELECT '20', 'Twenty'
    UNION ALL SELECT '30', 'Thirty'   UNION ALL SELECT '40', 'Forty'
    UNION ALL SELECT '50', 'Fifty'    UNION ALL SELECT '60', 'Sixty'
    UNION ALL SELECT '70', 'Seventy'  UNION ALL SELECT '80', 'Eighty'
    UNION ALL SELECT '90', 'Ninety'   
END
GO
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('dbo.Tensomes') )
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tensomes (chunk int NOT NULL, tensone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT PK_Tensomes PRIMARY KEY (chunk))

INSERT INTO dbo.Tensomes   
SELECT 1, 'Thousand' UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Million'
UNION ALL SELECT  3, 'Billion'  UNION ALL SELECT  4, 'Trillion'
UNION ALL SELECT  5, 'Quadrillion' UNION ALL SELECT  6, 'Quintillion'
UNION ALL SELECT  7, 'Sextillion'  UNION ALL SELECT  8, 'Septillion'
UNION ALL SELECT  9, 'Octillion'  UNION ALL SELECT 10, 'Nonillion'
UNION ALL SELECT 11, 'Decillion'  UNION ALL SELECT 12, 'Undecillion'
END
GO
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.CurrencyToWords2 ( @Input Numeric (38, 3) -- Input number with as many as 18 digits
) RETURNS VARCHAR(8000) 
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @Number Numeric(38,0), @Cents as int, @inputNumber VARCHAR(38), @length INT,  @outputString VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT @Number = Floor(@Input), @Cents = 100*Convert(money,(@Input - convert(Numeric(38,3),@Number)))
, @inputNumber = CONVERT(varchar(38), @Number), @length   = LEN(@inputNumber)

;WITH b AS ( 
    SELECT CONVERT(int, (J-1)/3) chunk, (J-1)%3+1 p, f FROM (
        SELECT I, @length-I+1 J, SUBSTRING(@inputNumber,I,1) f FROM dbo.Num38 WHERE I <= @length ) a
) , c AS (
    SELECT chunk, [3], [2], [1] 
    , CASE  WHEN [3] >= '1' THEN '0'+[3] ELSE NULL END t3 
    , CASE  WHEN [2] >= '2' THEN [2]+'0' WHEN [2] = '1' THEN [2]+[1] 
            WHEN [2]  = '0' THEN CASE [1] WHEN '0' THEN '' ELSE '0'+[1] END ELSE NULL END t2
    , CASE  WHEN [2] >= '2' THEN '0'+[1] WHEN [3] IS NULL AND [2] IS NULL THEN '0'+[1] ELSE '' END t1
    FROM b PIVOT(MAX(f) FOR p IN ([3],[2],[1]) ) p
), d AS (
        SELECT chunk, [3], [2], [1], t3, t2, t1, n3.word w3, n2.word w2, n1.word w1
        FROM c
        LEFT JOIN dbo.NumbersTable n3 ON n3.number = t3
        LEFT JOIN dbo.NumbersTable n2 ON n2.number = t2
        LEFT JOIN dbo.NumbersTable n1 ON n1.number = t1 AND (t1 >= '01' OR (chunk = 0 AND [3] IS NULL AND [2] IS NULL))
), e AS (
    SELECT d.chunk -- , [3], [2], [1], t3, t2, t1, d.w3, d.w2, d.w1
    , CONCAT(ISNULL(w3+' Hundred'+CASE WHEN [2]>0 OR [1]>0 THEN ' ' ELSE '' END,'')
    , ISNULL(CASE WHEN t2>='20' AND t1>='01' THEN w2+'-' ELSE w2 END,''), ISNULL(w1+'',''), ISNULL(' '+t.tensone,'')) word
    FROM d LEFT JOIN dbo.Tensomes t ON t.chunk = CONVERT(int,d.chunk)
)--, f AS (
 SELECT @outputString = STRING_AGG(word+' ','') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY chunk DESC) +'Dollars' 
    + CASE WHEN @Cents >= 0 THEN CONCAT(' and ',@Cents,' Cents') ELSE '' END 
 FROM e WHERE word<>''
RETURN @outputString 
END 
GO
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?