# SQL Server scalar function to convert number to words with ordinal

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

How to build a scalar function in SQL server that converts a number to words with ordinal. 
Example : 
for input 25 output should be 'Twenty fifth'

Thank you.

Comment: programming wise it is good question but you don't handle such thing in database.

Comment: The database is definitely the wrong place to do this, but for giggles there are a couple of ways we might tackle this. What range are you looking to go to? Any number between 0 and 999?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to write number to word function in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673265/how-to-write-number-to-word-function-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Range 0 to 9999

```
 declare @t table(col1 int,col2 varchar(50),col3 int)
insert into @t (col1,col2) VALUES (0,'Zero'),(1,'One'),(2,'Two')
,(3,'Three'),(4,'Four'),(5,'Five'),(6,'Six'),(7,'Seven'),(8,'Eight')
,(9,'Nine'),(10,'Ten'),(11,'eleven'),(12,'Twelve'),(13,'thirteen')
,(14,'Fourteen'),(15,'Fifteen'),(16,'Sixteen'),(17,'Seventeen')
,(18,'Eighteen'),(19,'Nineteen'),(20,'Twenty'),(30,'Thirty'),(40,'Forty')
,(50,'Fifty'),(60,'Sixty'),(70,'Seventy'),(80,'Eighty'),(90,'Ninety')
,(100,'Hundreds'),(1000,'Thousands'),(10000,'Thousands')

    declare @input varchar(10)='1897'

    declare @Words varchar(2000)=''
    declare @i int=len(@input)

    while((len(@input)>0))
    begin

    if(@input>=0 and @input<=19 and @i=len(@input))
    begin
    select @Words=@Words+' '+ col2 from @t where col1 =@input
    BREAK
    END
    else if(len(@input) between 3 and 4)
    BEGIN
    select @Words=@Words+' '+ col2 from @t where col1 =@input/cast(('1'+replicate('0',len(@input)-1)) as int)
    select @Words=@Words+' '+ col2 from @t where col1 ='1'+replicate('0',len(@input)-1)
    END
    else
    begin
    select @Words=@Words+' '+ col2 from @t where col1 =left(@input,1)+ replicate('0',@i-1)

    END
    set @input=stuff(@input,1,1,'')
    if(cast(@input as int)=0)
    BREAK
    set @i=@i-1


    end
    select @Words
```